# iPhone 5 not zooming on page load

Tags: iphone, mobile, zooming, viewport, responsive

I have just created a site that has been mobile optimised.  However, I have set a min-width on the page to 350px which seems to be 30px larger than an Iphone 5s screen.

To counter this I tried to put

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=350, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

as well as other variants, including removing the maximum scale, initial scale adding no user scrolling

If I remove both initial and maximum and use device-width, it loads up fitting on the screen but then expands once the page has loaded

No matter what I try, I always seem to get the scrolling on the iPhone.  Does anyone know how to make the page start so it fits on the screen (without breaking the layout for other mobiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that when my min-width is too large for some screens, I need to use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

And then add the following to my css:

```
@media (max-width: 350px) {
  @viewport {
    width: 350px;
  }
}
```

Where 350 is the min-width of the site

Comment: Awesome, this works, thanks!  Will accept when it lets me